# django-celery-beat break django unexpectedly

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I am working with django-celery-beat with celery 4.2.1 and django2.

At first it works perfect but after some time in gunicorn log appears the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/infra/app/smartwaypanel-backend/src/restfull_api/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from celery.five import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible'
```

It is a very strange behaviour and I cannont find more information about.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
from celery.five import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

by

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the end was that I was using different versions for celery and gunicorn, fixing that all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this happened after upgrading from 4.4.7 to 5.0.5

```
    from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule, CrontabSchedule


File "/home/someUser/PycharmProjects/some-project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from celery.five import python_2_unicode_compatible
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.five'
```

downgraded back to celery==4.4.7 no issues

the package `python_2_unicode_compatible` seems to be dislocated?